# Polychoric correlation (Stata) using multiple imputations and a complex sample design

Tags: stata, correlation

I have a data base (I use Stata 13) that has multiple imputations with a complex sample design (Strate and Pweight), so I generally use the following command before my analysis : `mi estimate, esampvaryok:svy:`

I just want to know is there any way to use the `polychoric` command in Stata in that context? Or, if it's not possible, do you know other software that would allow me to do so?

Comment: It's good practice to mention where commands come from if not from the Stata base installation. `polychoric` is a user-written command made available running `findit polychoric`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply `polychoric` to each imputation data set and then average the results. Although `polychoric` is not survey-aware, only the probability weights are needed to estimate the correlations. Here's code that computes two estimates of the correlations: 1) the average of the individual correlations from `polychoric`; 2) an estimate based on the average inverse-hyperbolic-tangent transform of those correlations. In the example they are similar, but I'd usually prefer the latter. See: Nick Cox, Speaking Stata: Correlation with confidence, or Fisher’s z revisited. The Stata Journal (2008) 8, Number 3, pp. 413–439. http://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=pr0041.

**Update** : Output the correlations to Stata matrices and added row & column names

```
/* Create MI data set */
set seed 43228226
sysuse auto, clear
recode rep78 1/2=3
replace foreign = . in 3/5
mi set flong
mi register impute rep78 foreign
mi impute chained ///
(ologit) rep78  ///
(logit) foreign =  turn weight mpg ///
[pw = turn], add(5) double

/* Set up polychoric */

/* local macro with variables */
local pvars rep78 foreign mpg weight

local nvars : word count("`pvars'")
mata: nv = strtoreal(st_local("nvars"))

qui mi des
mata: nreps = st_numscalar("r(M)")

/* loop through MI data sets to get sums*/
mata: sum_r = J(nv,nv,0)
mata: sum_atr = J(nv,nv,0)

forvalues i = 1/`=r(M)'{
qui polychoric `pvars' [pw = turn] if _mi_m==`i'
mata: r = st_matrix("r(R)")
mata: sum_r = sum_r  + r
mata: sum_atr = sum_atr +atanh(r)
}
/* Now average and get estimates */
mata:
st_matrix("rho1",sum_r/nreps)
/* For version based on atanh:
1) Get average of atanh transforms.
2) Diagonal elements are missing; substitute 0s.
3) Back transform to correlation scale.
4) Put 1s on diagonal.
5) Make the matrix symmetric. */
 st_matrix("rho2",  ///
 makesymmetric(tanh(lowertriangle(sum_atr/nreps,0))) +I(nv))
end


/* rho1 : average correlations
   rho2 : back transform of average atanh(r) */
forvalues i = 1/2 {
mat colnames rho`i' = `pvars'
mat rownames rho`i' = `pvars'
mat list rho`i'
}
```

**Update 2: Mostly Mata**

```
/* Set up variables & pweight  */
local pcvars rep78 foreign mpg weight
local pwtvar turn

mata:
stata("qui mi query")
M= st_numscalar("r(M)") 

vnames = tokens(st_local("pcvars"))
nv = cols(vnames)

/*Initialize sums for average numerators */
sum_r = J(nv,nv,0)
sum_atr = J(nv,nv,0)

/* Run -polychoric- on each imputed data set */
for (j = 1; j<=M; j++) {
  st_numscalar("j",j)
  stata("qui polychoric `pcvars' [pw = `pwtvar'] if _mi_m==j")
  r = st_matrix("r(R)")
  sum_r = sum_r  + r
  sum_atr = sum_atr + atanh(r)
}
/* Create Stata correlation matrices from average over imputations*/
st_matrix("rho1",sum_r/M)
st_matrix("rho2",  ///
  makesymmetric(tanh(lowertriangle(sum_atr/M,0))) +I(nv))

/* Label rows & columns */
c =  (J(nv,1,""),vnames')
st_matrixrowstripe("rho1",c)
st_matrixcolstripe("rho1",c)

st_matrixrowstripe("rho2",c)
st_matrixcolstripe("rho2",c)
end

mat list rho1
mat list rho2
```

Comment: You are very welcome. If you like the answer, please accept it.  I've added an alternative version of the  analysis code.  You specify the variables for `polychoric` and the probability weight at the top. This version might be a little faster than the original, because it's practically all in Mata, with the exceptions being a line for  `mi query` (a replacement for `mi des`) and one for `polychoric`.